# Does ibm-eventstreams support Kafka ACLs?

Tags: apache-kafka, ibm-cloud-private, ibm-eventstreams

Wanted to check if ibm-eventstreams that I can deploy on IBM Cloud Private (ICP) 2.1.0.3, supports Kafka SASL authentication and ACLs applied to specific topics?

I was referring to this developerWorks article about Kafka ACLs:
https://developer.ibm.com/opentech/2017/05/31/kafka-acls-in-practice/

Wondering whether it is available and supported with ibm-eventstreams.
If it is supported, are there any changes/enhancements to the ACL support that I see in the above doc? Is there any further documentation available?

Answer (score 1):

Sorry, no - the current Tech Preview doesn't include any security or auth. (We're thinking hard about what the best way to do this would be though!)

Comment: Thanks @dalelane, is this in near term roadmap to add auth/security features to IBM Event Streams? I will need to switch back to Apache Kafka on ICP till the event-streams gets the built in support.

Comment: @nilesh-bhosale : Today IBM Event Streams is a tech-preview, so is intended to gather feedback just like this.  Security is obviously a really important topic for us and we have a sponsor user program if you'd like to collaborate on how we're looking at this.  Join our public slack for details of how to sign up: https://ibm-cloud-tech.slack.com/messages/CADFRM4FR - thanks!